# Can you regexp.Split a string with regexp not containing word in golang?

Tags: regex, go

I write a function which takes a string list of numbers, list items separator reg and range separator reg like:

```
func ParseList(list string, ls, rs *regexp.Regexp) (...) {
  ...
  for _, item := range ls.Split(list, -1) {
    for _, rng := range rs.Split(item, -1) {
      range_start, _ := strconv.ParseInt(rng[0])
      range_end := range_start
      if len(rng) > 1 {
        range_end, _ = strconv.ParseInt(rng[1])
      }
      ... save or analyse range
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Input string could be, but not limited to:
`1,3,5-10,15-20`
`1;3;5-10;15-20`
`1 3 5 to 10 15 to 20`

So for first example regexps are easy, but third gives a problem, because list separator is " " and range separator also has " ".

UPDATE:

So i followed Trung Duong's suggestion and switched from "splitter" to "extractor" regexp like this:

```
func ParseList(list string, ex, rs *regexp.Regexp) (...) {
  ...
  for _, item := range ex.FindAllString(list, -1) {
    for _, rng := range rs.Split(item, -1) {
      range_start, _ := strconv.ParseInt(rng[0])
      range_end := range_start
      if len(rng) > 1 {
        range_end, _ = strconv.ParseInt(rng[1])
      }
      ... save or analyse range
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

So now i can use `(\d+-\d+)|(\d+)` or `(\d+ to \d+)|(\d+)` to extract ranges, and then split them.

Comment: Negative lookaheads might be able to do this. The reason they might not work is that they require fixed length matches.

Comment: Not easy to split so, but `FindAllStringSubmatch` with `\d+( to \d+)?` should work. As @Ouroborus says, you can convert this into a split condition using lookahead for this expression or end of string.

Comment: Might be easier to split on space and then rejoin elements around `"to"`.

Comment: there are also this kind of lists: ```1,3,5-7,8-100``` and ```1;3;5-7;8-100```
I'm writing a function, which takes list string and two regexes as items separator and range separator. So i dont want to write separate function for each kind of lists.
All three components will be user-input, and there could be another variants of lists also. The input is VLANs list and different vendors may use different semantic.

Comment: @Ouroborus, golang does not support lookaheads as i understand https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this pattern: `(\d+\s+to\s+\d+)|(\d+)`

See regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/fe3Kh5/1).

Comment: Interesing approach. Not intuitive though.

Comment: The more i think of it, the more i like it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm You need.
We can simply do this with the help of iterations.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    inputString := "1 2 7 to 10 15 16 to 20"

    // Split the string by space to get individual elements
    elements := strings.Split(inputString, " ")

    // Initialize a slice to store the output
    output := []string{}

    // Iterate through the elements
    i := 0
    for i < len(elements) {
        // If the element contains "to", it means it's a range
        if strings.Contains(elements[i], "to") {
            // Get the start and end of the range
            rangeEnds := strings.Split(elements[i], "to")
            start, _ := strconv.Atoi(rangeEnds[0])
            end, _ := strconv.Atoi(rangeEnds[1])
            // Add the range to the output
            output = append(output, fmt.Sprintf("%d to %d", start, end))
            i++
        } else {
            // If the element is not a range, simply add it to the output
            output = append(output, elements[i])
            i++
        }
    }

    // Print the output
    for _, element := range output {
        fmt.Println(element)
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
2
7 to 10
15
16 to 20
```